# Ajax post array (empty)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to post an associative array by an ajax call but the array i send is always empty (chrome network debug)

My ajax call

```
function getAssurance(passagers)
{
    console.log(passagers);

    var postdata =  JSON.stringify({psg:passagers});

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: rootUrl + "/b2c/searchAssurance",
        data: postdata,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    }); 
}
```

The array is correct in my console.log()

My route

```
Route::post('/b2c/searchAssurance', 'VolControllerB2C@searchAssurance');
```

My controller

```
 public function searchAssurance()
    {
        $search_data = Input::get('psg');

        log::error(print_r($search_data,true));

        echo "ok";
    }
```

Where i build my array

```
var valide = true;
            var psgDetails = [];

            if($("#country").val() == "-1")
            {
                valide = false;
            }

            if($("#state").val() == "0")
            {
                valide = false;
            }

            if($("#phone_0").val() == "0")
            {
                valide = false;
            }

            if(valide)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i<$("#nb").val(); i++)
                {
                    var onePsg = [];

                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        onePsg['country'] = $("#country").val();
                        onePsg['state'] = $("#state").val();
                        onePsg['phone_0'] = $("#phone_0").val();
                    }

                    if($("#title_"+i).val() == "0")
                    {
                        valide = false;
                    }

                    if($("#name_"+i).val().length < 1)
                    {
                        valide = false;
                    }

                    if($("#lastname_"+i).val().length < 1)
                    {
                        valide = false;
                    }

                    if($("#dob_day_"+i).val() == "Day")
                    {
                        valide = false;
                    }

                    if($("#dob_month_"+i).val() == "Month")
                    {
                        valide = false;
                    }

                    if($("#dob_year_"+i).val() == "Year")
                    {
                        valide = false;
                    }

                    onePsg["title"] = $("#title_"+i).val();
                    onePsg['name'] = $("#name_"+i).val();
                    onePsg['lastname'] = $("#lastname_"+i).val();
                    onePsg['dob_day'] = $("#dob_day_"+i).val();
                    onePsg['dob_month'] = $("#dob_month_"+i).val();
                    onePsg['dob_year'] = $("#dob_year_"+i).val();

                    psgDetails.push(onePsg);
                }
            }

            if(valide)
            {
                console.log(psgDetails);
                getAssurance(psgDetails);
                $("#assurance").show("slow");
                $("#assuranceArrow").toggleClass('arrow-down arrow-up');
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#assurance').offset().top }, 200);
            }
```

Anyone know what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: how you call getAssurance() and how you inject passagers argument?

Comment: first return Input::all(); and check all data are reach to controller or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which framework you are using but...
In your backend method seems you are receiving the data using **get** but you are sending the data with jQuery using **post**:

```
    public function searchAssurance()
        {
            // HERE you should use "post" to receive the data in your framework
            $search_data = Input::get('psg');
        }
```

**Note:** if you are using Laravel, my answer is not right, since Input::get is used for all HTTP verbs;

Comment: Yes, i am using laravel. but when i debug my ajax post in chrome network, my array is already empty

Comment: What is the output in this conditional?
`if (valide) {
    console.log(psgDetails); // Is this getting the data?
    ...
}`

Comment: Maybe your line with the `psgDetails.push(onePsg);` is never executed; and for that reason you don't see the data that you will send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but don't stringify the variable before sending it by ajax:

```
function getAssurance(passagers)
{
    console.log(passagers);

    //don't: var postdata =  JSON.stringify({psg:passagers});

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: rootUrl + "/b2c/searchAssurance",
        data: postdata,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Still have the same problem with var postdata =  {psg:passagers};